# How to assign a bool variable directly using a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, if-statement

I am really new to this style of assigning a condition to a bool variable.

Say for example, I have this

```
bool type;

if (((sDataSet.Shipment[0].CI_TYPE == Constants.ShipType.CI_R) &&
                         (shipType == Constants.ShipType.CI_R)) ||
    ((sDataSet.Shipment[0].CI_TYPE == Constants.ShipType.CI_P) &&
                         (shipType == Constants.ShipType.CI_R)) ||
    ((sDataSet.Shipment[0].CI_TYPE == Constants.ShipType.CI_R) &&
                         (shipType == Constants.ShipType.CI_P)))
    type = true;
else 
    type = false;
```

How to directly assign this condition in type bool? Optimized or better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign your variable to the if statement, but remove the if. Like this:

```
type = (((sDataSet.Shipment[0].CI_TYPE == Constants.ShipType.CI_R) &&
                             (shipType == Constants.ShipType.CI_R)) ||
            ((sDataSet.Shipment[0].CI_TYPE == Constants.ShipType.CI_P) &&
                            (shipType == Constants.ShipType.CI_R))  ||
            ((sDataSet.Shipment[0].CI_TYPE == Constants.ShipType.CI_R) &&
                            (shipType == Constants.ShipType.CI_P)))
```

Comment: Thank you, it gives some error "only assignments is possible"

Comment: @Divine then search the web for the **exact** error. Also, you're asking for _"optimized or better way"_, which is the wrong question. There is no optimization in this, it is purely cosmetic.

Comment: Thank you, my bad, you are GOD it helped me, but when I did same last time, it gave me some stupid error. Now it is not :0

Comment: By default if I say bool type;, what is the value assigned by compiler by default if we don't assign anything but just declare? Is it true or false?

Comment: @Divine see [Default Values Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much for your earnest help Marciano and CodeCaster. I am new :( It helped me now :) Thank you again.

Comment: no problem. Just take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask , and mark my answer as correct. Ty

Comment: Oh sorry, I wanted to mark at that time only, but unfortunately it said I need to wait 9 mins before I mark it correct because I already gave one vote :) :) Thank you